# SQL select all files where a value in table A is the same as in table B (same database)

Tags: php, sql

I'm building a sales system for a company, but I'm stuck with the following issue.

Every day I load .XML `productfeed` into a database called `items`. The rows in the `productfeed` are never in the same order, so sometimes the row with `Referentie = 380083` is at the very top, and the other day that very same row is at the very bottum.

I also have to get all the `instock` value, but when I run the following query

```
SELECT `instock` FROM SomeTable WHERE `id` > 0
```

I get all values, but not in the same order as in the other table.

So I have to get the `instock` value of all rows where `referentie` in table A is the same as it is in table B.

I already have this query:

```
select * from `16-11-23 wed 09:37` where `referentie` LIKE '4210310AS'
```

and this query does the right job, but I have like 500 rows in the table.

So I need to find a way to automate the: `LIKE '4210310AS'` bit, so it selects all 500 values in one go.

Can somebody tell me how that can be done?

Comment: `but I have like 500 rows` ... exactly, `LIKE` will be applied on 500 rows.

Comment: Exactly, query works in a method exactly as in a way we spell it

Comment: You table name is a timestamp? Really? And what does the sort order have to do with all this?

Comment: people, A client is trying to save the maintenance cost here :P

Comment: Why LIKE without wildcards?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not even sure I understand your problem...

Don't take this personally, but you seem to be concerned/confused by the ordering of the data in the tables which suggests to me your understanding of relational databases and SQL is lacking. I suggest you brush up on the basics.

Can't you just use the following query?

```
SELECT a.referentie
     , b.instock
  FROM tableA a
     , tableB b
 WHERE b.referentie = a.referentie
```